# How to catch CSRF errors in Django

Tags: python, django, error-handling

How would I go about catching CSRF errors in Django?
For example, I would like to catch this: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /asdjasdjk/asdhriheiof

I want to do this because I want to ban people who tamper with CSRF codes for my particular case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At first, CSRF is checked in a middleware name CSRFViewMiddleware so what you need is, you need to override the middleware with your own middleware and catch the error in it. or read the documentation of this middleware  you will get the hooks for it

Answer (score 0):

One way that I know about catching CSRF errors is by adding the following setting to your settings.py:

```
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'app_name.views.csrf_failure'
```

Then on your app views.py:

```
# This will get called when there is a csrf error.
def csrf_failure(request, reason=""):
    # Do stuff here.
    return HttpResponse(status=403)
```

You can read more about CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW).

Another way is by overriding the CsrfViewMiddleware class like this:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware

class CustomCsrfMiddleware(CsrfViewMiddleware):

    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):
        # You can do things here before the error is raised.
        return super(CustomCsrfMiddleware, self).process_view(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
```

Then in your settings.py, remove the old csrf middleware and add yours:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'app_name.view.CustomCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Hopefully this is helpful.